# Multiple checkboxes doesn't get pre-checked with jquery. From Php/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to populate multiple checkbox with the help of earlier mysql entries.
I have the data in a variabel:
var = ObjektLevHur;
The data can be: frittlev, frittfabrik or mont.
In my first .change id=1 is ticked. Then if i made a second change id=2 is ticked. etc?!
why?

HTML: Jquery should tick the boxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="valt_objekt_lev_hur" id="valt_objekt_lev_hur-1" value="mont">
<input type="checkbox" name="valt_objekt_lev_hur" id="valt_objekt_lev_hur-2" value="mont">
```

JS: The select2('data').olevhur; is is populating var objektLevHur with: frittlev, frittfabrik or mont.

```
$(valtObjekt).change(function() {
var objektLevHur = $(valtObjekt).select2('data').olevhur;
if(objektLevHur == "frittlev"){
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-0').prop("checked",true);
    }
    else if(objektLevHur == "frittfabrik"){
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-1').prop("checked",true);
    }
    else if(objektLevHur == "mont"){
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-2').prop("checked",true);
    }
```

PHP: "olevhur" is an array created in PHP, then encoded to JSON and sended to JS/AjaxCall

```
"olevhur"=>$row['objekt_lev_hur'],
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete... Do you mean the change event ?

Comment: what more you want to achieve that your code doesn't do?

Comment: Can you show a fiddle?

Comment: @Loenix Yes. The change event doesn't pre-check the boxes!

Comment: @StormRideR My code doesn't work ;)

Comment: @PraveenKumar i guess not. Because i use php to get data from mysql. Then i send data threw ajax to Js. Then i use jquery to control the HTML =) ?

Comment: @Loenix Now is my question complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the checkboxes didn't "un-tick" when a .change was called!
This solved my problem!

```
if(objektLevHur == "fritt_lev"){
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-0').prop("checked",true);
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-1').prop("checked",false);
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-2').prop("checked",false);
    }
    else if(objektLevHur == "fritt_fab"){
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-0').prop("checked",false);
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-1').prop("checked",true);
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-2').prop("checked",false);
    }
    else if(objektLevHur == "mont"){
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-0').prop("checked",false);
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-1').prop("checked",false);
        $('#valt_objekt_lev_hur-2').prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: if that was your problem  you should just use radio buttons instead of checkbox.

Comment: @StormRideR Thank you. I did change to radio buttons!

Answer (score 1):

first thing i see is that ObjektLevHur is not objektLevHur. change name

Comment: @nem answered 38min ago - question edited 11 min ago, lot of things have changed since then.